# Analysis of the sign of $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Let $f : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be any twice differentiable function satisfying

$f(ax + (1-a)y) \leq a f(x) + (1-a)f(y)$ ,for all $x,y \in [0,1]$ and any $a \in [0,1]$.

Then for all $x \in (0,1)$  -
what can we say about the sign of $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ ?

I can only make observations though -

1) when we see the argument of $f$ in the inequality it reminds me of the parametric equation of a line segment.

2) Also when $f$ is a linear function then the above equality holds so can we say any thing about the characterisation of functions in which $\leq$ or $\geq$ holds.

3)seeing the interval hint's me of applying mean value theorem but how ?

Any help is great!

Comment: You might want to read about convex function: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvexFunction.html

Comment: The first derivative can have either sign (e.g., $1/x$ and $e^x$) but is nondecreasing. The second derivative is nonnegative. Everything follows for a twice differentiable function from the basic convexity result that for $u < v < w$ we have $(f(v)-f(u))/(v-u) \leqslant (f(w)-f(u))/(w-u) \leqslant (f(w) - f(v))/(w-v)$.  Try proving that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the inequality follow's from the definition of a function $f$  to be a convex function.
As per the comments above, aresource for convex function - http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvexFunction.html

And as per the property of a convex function $f''(x) \geq 0$  and  sign of $f'(x)$ could be either $< $ or $> 0$ but should be non-decreasing .